# Run command through External Tools Configuration in Eclipse on Mac

Tags: eclipse, macos, shell, command-line, command

I'm try to execute the following string of commands through a an External Tools Configuration in Eclipse (it basically deploys a build to a server and touches the server's plan file, causing the server to update itself with the new build):

```
mvn -P virgo package -o -Dmaven.test.skip=true && touch ${env_var:SERVER_HOME}/pickup/{project_name}.plan
```

On Windows, I was able to pass this string (with slight modifications) to `cmd.exe` using its `/c` argument and see the output in Eclipse's Console.

How can I get this behavior on Mac?

**UPDATE**

Another way of phrasing the question is, how can one feed an argument to Terminal to be execute (i.e., `Terminal.app -argument "mvn -P virgo package -o -Dmaven.test.skip=true && touch ${env_var:SERVER_HOME}/pickup/{project_name}.plan"`)?

Another possibility would be to use a shell script, but I don't have experience with them.